# How to work with database from eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have a MySQL database server installed on my local machine. I have connected it with eclipse data source explorer.

can you please point me to tutorials on effectively working with the database from eclipse itself without using command line MySQL client ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [QuantumDB plugin](http://quantum.sourceforge.net/) is pretty good.